# Why is the de Rham complex elliptic?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, de-rham-cohomology

I need to show that the exterior derivative

$$ \mathrm{d} : \Omega^r(M) \to \Omega^{r+1}(M) $$

is an elliptic differential operator. As far as I understand it, an elliptic operator is one such that the symbol $\sigma(\mathrm{d},\xi)$ is an invertible linear map for all non-zero $\xi$. In this case, we have

$$ \sigma(\mathrm{d},\xi) = \xi  \,\wedge  $$

(up to a factor of $i$ perhaps), which is clearly not invertible. Indeed, the dimensions of the fibres it maps between are different! I'm sure I'm missing something blindingly obvious here, but I've searched all over the web and haven't found anything that clears this up. Thanks.

Comment: An elliptic complex is not a complex in which each operator is elliptic, so you don't need to show that $d^r$ is elliptic (this is not true and not relevant) but something rather different. For details, see for example 'Notes on the Atiyah-Singer index theorem" by Nicolaescu.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Having now seen the correct definition of an elliptic complex, am I then right in saying that the link between an elliptic complex and an elliptic operator is the non-trivial result that "a complex is elliptic if and only if the operator $\mathrm{D}+\mathrm{D}^\dagger$ is elliptic"?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.